# How would i use array_intersect() with the arrays in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, parameters, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

I have a dynamic amount of arrays in a specific array. 
Let's call this specific array: **FatherArray** 

This **FatherArray** has a dynamic amount of arrays in it, right now for example: **Child1Array**,**Child2Array**. Next time it gets called it could have more or less than those 2 Child(number)Arrays.


 
So I want to use the function array_intersect() with the arrays (children) of **FatherArray** as parameters, so like array_intersect(Child1Array,Child2Array).

I don't have a clue how i could do this dynamically, neither could I find anything about it, any help would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version is reasonably new ([v5.6](https://secure.php.net/manual/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)):

```
array_intersect(...$FatherArray);
```

Otherwise:

```
call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $FatherArray);
```

Demo: see comment by Mark (thx @MarkBaker)

Comment: [Demonstration](https://3v4l.org/p5Ztp) and [Demonstration 2](https://3v4l.org/OsV3A)

Comment: Thanks, however it returns an empty array for me. When i manually add it like array_intersect($FatherArray[0],$FatherArray[1]) it works fine. Thanks for the help so far tho! Edit: nvm, i am dumb. FatherArray[2] was empty..

Comment: @Christiaan Please add your code to the question, otherwise I can't tell what might  be wrong.

Comment: If you want to "ignore" empty child arrays, then `$result = array_intersect(...array_filter($fatherArray));` or `call_user_func_array('array_intersect', array_filter($fatherArray));`